# Software to test accuracy in vocally repeating notes after listening and identifying

Tags: voice, software

**Background**

Listening and identifying a note is a difficult task for many of us who are beginners to singing. Even when we singing, we are often not certain as to how close we were to the actual note. Experienced singers, on the other hand, can very easily tell, whether one has hit the right note, or not, and in the latter case, which was the note one actually sang.

I have been taking vocals classes, for some time, and my teacher stressed on the fact that it is very important to accurately register a note before trying to sing it. She advised me to do this exercise to improve - randomly play notes, one by one, on a keyboard, identify it and repeat it vocally.

**What I need**

I know there would be keyboard/piano softwares available, but I was wondering if there is something advanced available. I would like a software which could take my voice input and compare it with the actual sound of the note produced by it and tell me how accurate it was.

Note - I checked this question - [Singing software](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/singing-software). However I am not sure if a karaoke software is exactly what I need, because I am stressing on individual notes here, rather than a complete song. So asking a new question...

Comment: Welcome to Music SE! Per the [FAQ], questions eliciting recommendations are off-topic here. If you have questions about a specific software, feel free to ask.

Comment: A simple tuner wouldn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but this app seems pretty popular for audio=>note analysis
http://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/screenshots.html

Of course, the point of hitting a key and singing to it... 
 is to tune your ear to recognizing the sound as well as your voice creating it.

good luck to ya.